# What is the most efficient and unmessy way to pass data to a VC without segue?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

The scenario is I have an unattached VC in the storyboard that I want programmatically presented over and over again. Essentially, imagine this VC as the "reply" VC to a comment. As you can imagine, all replies are the same, so really, I'm just pushing to the same VC over and over again, until the last comment has no reply.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I imagined this as being the most efficient way to do such a task? I can just programmatically call the same reply VC (even to itself) when needed. My biggest concern is how to pass data around like such without the segue. Nor will I abuse NSNotifications or globals, those are for obvious reasons way to messy for a task like this...

Just wanted some ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Your first question is how do you save a pointer to this view controller. If you always invoke it from the same source view controller then you can create it with instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier and keep a pointer to it in an instance variable. then you can present/push it when you want to display it.

Once you have a pointer to it, just set up one or more properties in the view controller and set them before invoking it:

```
targetViewController.inputData = dataIWantToPass
self.presentViewController(targetViewContrller, 
  animated: yes, 
  completion: nil)
```

Alternately, if you need to invoke your ReplyVC from lots of different places you could make it a singleton and then just use the singleton class method to fetch the controller when you are ready to push/present it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're going to be presenting this VC from different places I'd create a extension of UIViewController with something like:

```
extension UIViewController {
    static func loadReply(data data: String) {
        let identifier = "ReplyIdentifier"
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "StoryboardName", bundle: nil)
        let replyVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(identifier) as! ReplyViewController
        replyVC.data = data
        return replyVC
    }
}
```

Then when you need to use it you can just do

```
let replyVC = UIViewController.loadReply(data: "yourData")
presentViewController(replyVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Just remember to set the identifier of your ViewController in the Storyboard.

Comment: An extension is probably overkill.  You could use a simple factory class method on the `UIViewController` subclass

Comment: Agreed, if you're just going to use it in one VC subclass, probably better to go with Paulw11 suggestion.